# I need to understand where create sqlite database using setDatabase("dbname") function

Tags: qt

I am creating a database application. My code runs fine. But I do not find the created database. I can not find on sqlite consol window too. It only show what I created manually.

Here is my code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("student.db");
    db.open ();

    //check
    qDebug() << "Database is open: " << db.isOpen ();
    qDebug() << "Database is valid: " << db.isValid ();

    //database open or not
    if (!db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: connection with database failed";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Database: connection ok";
    }

    //create query
    QSqlQuery query;

    //create tables
    query.prepare ("CREATE TABLE student_info(sid integer primary key, name text)");

    //insert data
    query.prepare ("INSERT INTO student_info VALUES(1, 'Hasibul')");
    query.prepare ("INSERT INTO student_info VALUES(2, 'Hasib')");
    query.prepare ("INSERT INTO student_info VALUES(3, 'Hasan')");

    //query all data
    query.prepare ("SELECT * FROM student_info");

    //execute query
    if(!query.exec ()){
        QMessageBox::critical (this, "Database Error!", query.lastQuery (), QMessageBox::Ok);
    } else {
        QMessageBox::information (this, "Database Information!", "Successful.", QMessageBox::Ok);
    }

    //find data from database and print
    while(query.next ()){
        int id = query.value (0).toInt ();
        QString name = query.value (1).toString ();

        qDebug() << id << name << endl;
    }

    //after finish work close database
    db.close ();
```

I have created loan_manager.db but I dont know how to connect with setDatabaseName(); Any way to connect existing database ? Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using? Did you look inside the folder where the executable of your application is? Did you look inside your user's home directory? Normally just giving the file name (without any extra path) uses the working directory of the process which is the same directory where the executable was started from.

Comment: Thanks. I found the db into build folder. How to connect into existing database what i created using sqlite. How to view data ?

Answer (score 1):

The `setDatabaseName` means different things to different database backends. For SQLITE, it means: *"set the database file name"*.

> How to connect into existing database that I created using sqlite.

Provide its *absolute path* to `setDatabaseName`.